# Sonarqube: How to use xml report in integration test coverage widget?

Tags: integration-testing, code-coverage, sonarqube, ncover

I'm using this command:

```
sonar.cs.ncover3.reportsPaths=glresults.nccov
```

to display code coverage data to the Unit Test Coverage widget in Sonarqube from a NCover 3 generated xml file.  How do I display this data through the Integration Test Coverage widget?  The only examples I've been able to find are with the Gallio plugin, which I've had a lot of trouble with and is not supported by Sonar anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported yet. Feel free to comment and vote for [SONARNTEST-5](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARNTEST-5).